# how change the value on change select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I change the values in the second `select` on change of the first one?

When I change to `Cool drink` then show `Pepsi`, `Coac` & `Sprite` only. When I change to `Food` then show `Pizza`, `Chicken` & `Bar b Q`

```html
<select id="food">
  <option>Cool Drink</option>
  <option>Food</option>
</select>
<select id="Person">
  <option>Pepsi</option>
  <option>Coac</option>
  <option>Sprite</option>
  <option>Bar b Q</option>
  <option>Chicken</option>
  <option>Pizza</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be by using ajax.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Food Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="food" >
        <option value="1">Cool Drink</option>
        <option value="2">Food</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Person" >
        <option>Select Option</option>
    </select>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#food").change(function(){
            var txt=$("#food").val();
            $("#Person").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'load.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {txt:txt},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#Person").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Add another page with the name of (load.php) and add this code

```
<?php $data=$_POST['txt'];  ?>
<?php if ($data == 1): ?>
        <option>Pepsi</option>
        <option>Coac</option>
        <option>Sprite</option>
<?php else: ?>
        <option>Bar b Q</option>
        <option>Chicken</option>
        <option>Pizza</option>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as I could make it. Very weird we cannot use :visible on the options

```js
$('#food').on("change",() => {
  const $opts = $('#Person option');
  $opts.each((_,el) => $(el).toggleClass("hidden"));
  $('#Person').val($opts.not('.hidden').eq(0).val());
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="food">
  <option>Cool Drink</option>
  <option>Food</option>
</select>
<select id="Person">
  <option value="1">Pepsi</option>
  <option value="2">Coca Cola</option>
  <option value="3">Sprite</option>
  <option value="4" class="hidden">Bar b Q</option>
  <option value="5" class="hidden">Chicken</option>
  <option value="6" class="hidden">Pizza</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Crate list of drinks and food in JS.

```
const drinks = ["Pepsi", "Cola"];
const food = ["Pizza 1", "Pizza 2"]
```

and then create JS function, which will be fired by event **onChange** and update second dropdown list.

```
function changeList(name){
    if (name === "Food") { 
         // fill list with foods
    }
    // fill list with drinks
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change the second dropdown contents depending on the data-type attribute of the first select on an onChange event. See below.

```js
$('#food').on('change', function(){
 
  const drink = ["Pepsi", "Coac", "Sprite"];
  const food = ["Bar b Q", "Chicken", "Pizza"]

  let type = $(this).children(":selected").data('type')
  
  var $dropdown = $("#Person");
  
  if (type=='food') {
   arr = food
  }  else if (type=='drink') {
   arr = drink
  } 

 $dropdown.find('option').remove();
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $dropdown.append($("<option />").text(arr[i]));
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Food Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="food" >
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option data-type="drink">Cool Drink</option>
        <option data-type="food">Food</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Person" >
      <option>Please Select Type</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would want to autoselect or have a "please select" on this code

Comment: This is on the right track, compared to the other answers. But still way too complicated for such a simple task